# Why does The Hulk alternate between removing his torn shirt and leaving it in the 70's and 80's TV shows?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, the-incredible-hulk-1978

Why, in the 70's and 80's TV show, does The Hulk only sometimes remove his torn shirt and in other scenes leaves it on, covering his body?

Comment: Why not? Sometimes I take my shirt off when I'm doing things and sometimes I don't

Comment: Out-of-universe, it was probably to save on makeup time

Answer (score 1):

In at least one episode, the Hulk ripping off the tatters of Banner's shirt is used like an actor dramatically taking off his glasses to appear more rugged.